# Swift 3 - SIGABRT when trying to retrieve data from FirebaseSnapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following this tutorial on implementing the Firebase Database into my app: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeZ3i7-gaok&list=PLy9JCsy2u97kro0jXbXrPFmT-DQVAmNW0&index=4)

When I try to retrieve the data in the 'events' tree, the app crashes. Currently, I'm attempting this through

```
let date = events[(self.events.count - 1) - (indexPath).row]?.value("date") as! String
```

and it's throwing a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, at that line.
The console is telling me

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRDataSnapshot 0x17003f680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key date.'
```

So what am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

[image: My code showing the error]

[image: My Firebase Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the code you're using to fetch the date.

`let date = events[(self.events.count - 1) - (indexPath).row]?.value("date") as! String`

Based on the structure of your data in Firebase, the above code is looking for the key "date" two levels below "events". In your Firebase data, the "date" key is three levels below events, not two. Here's what you can do to solve the problem:

`let oneStepBelow = events[(self.events.count - 1) - (indexPath).row] as! [AnyObject]`

`let secondStep = oneStepBelow[0].value("date") as! String`

This should solve your problem.